# Unable to play video in Hotstar (ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, firefox, video, flash, chromium

I tried to play video from [www.hotstar.com](http://www.hotstar.com) through Mozilla Firefox and Chromium both, but it was just buffering instead of playing:

[image: hotstar]

In chromium, I was recommended to install `adobe flashplugin` but after installing it was still showing that. There were somme errors while installing it:

[image: flashplugin installation]

Details:

- Ubuntu version:14.04 LTS
- Browse: Chromium and Mozilla Firefox
- Website of not-loading videos: [www.hotstar.com](http://www.hotstar.com)

Comment: Install the [adobe-flashplugin package](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).

Comment: sorry it does not work . -_-

Comment: http://www.hotstar.com/movies/abar-byomkesh/1000016540/watch

Comment: Can you see the flash version at [this page](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DreFx.png

Comment: Okay. Did you install the `adobe-flashplugin` package? What you show us indicates that you didn't.

Comment: just asking, are you from India ? Because hot star streaming is only available in India. Here from Singapore, when I play, I have the same problem as yours.

Comment: I am from bangladesh and it is avilable here .

Comment: yes I have install adobe-flashplugin package from software center

Answer (score 2):

Okay.. Looking at the screenshot again, and it looks like you have a couple of other Flash related packages installed as well. So I'd suggest that you clean it up a bit by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash pepperflashplugin-nonfree adobe-flashplugin
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Then restart your browsers.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DreFx.png
some problem found to install it :-(

Comment: @tanvirhossain: Which problem? Which error messages did you get when trying to install? Did you forget to enable [Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner)?

Comment: NO,I enable Canonical partner
but I get' Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'while installing it

Comment: @tanvirhossain: That's a quite separate problem. Maybe you want to ask another question about it.

Comment: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 adobe-flashplugin : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11.94) but 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
                     Recommends: adobe-flash-properties-gtk (= 1:20170110.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 adobe-flash-properties-kde (= 1:20170110.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming

Comment: @tanvirhossain: That's not a new question. Please ask a new question, where that output can be reasonably formatted.

Comment: is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: @tanvirhossain: Yes, ask a new Ask Ubuntu question about the "unmet dependencies" problem.

Comment: ok now I have installed it(adobe flashplugin) but it's again buffering -_-

Comment: is there any other solution for that

Comment: @tanvirhossain: I don't know; it's buffering for me too (I'm in Sweden), just as for tuxebin. Maybe you are not supposed to be able to view the videos from Bangladesh after all.

Comment: many of my friend are using it

Comment: @tanvirhossain: I'm not able to say more. Now you have the latest Flash plugins at least. Maybe someone else can help.